# Understanding Netplan IP address notation

Tags: networking, netplan

I have some questions about Netplan configuration and couldn't find any information about that:

1. I've seen that in order to indicate IP address you have to use the keyword `addresses`.

   This happens when configuring the IP address of the interface (`enp3s0`) or DNS servers (`nameservers`) but not when configuring the gateway (`gateway4`):

   ```yaml
   network:
     version: 2
     renderer: networkd
     ethernets:
       enp3s0:
         addresses:
           - 10.10.10.2/24
         nameservers:
           addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
         gateway4: 10.10.10.1
   ```
2. I've seen three different ways of IP notations

   - directly after the `:`, like in

   ```yaml
   gateway4: 10.10.10.1
   ```

   - in a new line using `-`, like in

   ```yaml
   enp3s0:
     addresses:
       - 10.10.10.2/24
   ```

   - using `[]`, like in

   ```yaml
   nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
   ```

   I am a bit confused about when to use each.

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue, could you please accept it so it's marked as containing solution and gets removed from the Unanaswered -queue?

Answer (score 5):

The answer lies in an understanding of YAML syntax.

YAML uses key/value pairs. A set of key/value pairs is a "mapping".
Values (in a key/value pair) can be single scalars, lists, or mappings.
Lists can be lists of scalars, lists, or mappings.
Lists can be put on a single line, enclosed by brackets [] and separated by commas, or lists can be put on individual lines with a hypen at the beginning of each list element. And the top level of a YAML file is a mapping, if we don't consider the multiple document feature.

The ip address here is a list of scalars, with only one element in the list.

```
  addresses:
  - 10.10.10.2/24
```

The ip addresses here is a list of two scalars, but all elements are on a single line.

```
  addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

The ip address here is a scalar.

```
  gateway4: 10.10.10.1
```

As you might guess, you can rewrite the first two like this if you wanted to.

```
  addresses: [10.10.10.2/24]

  addresses:
  - 8.8.8.8
  - 1.1.1.1
```

So it would appear that there can be only one gateway (a scalar), but there can be many addresses for nameservers and many addresses assigned to an interface.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [netplan reference](https://netplan.io/reference/)

1. The gateway addresses are always notated without the word
   "addresses".
2. Otherwise the notation depends consistently on what address you are configuring.

Interface addresses preceded by - and written indented underneath the interface name:

```
enp3s0:
    addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2/24
```

Gateway addresses written on the same line with the keywoard "gateway":

```
gateway4: 10.10.10.1
```

Gateway is deprecated in favour of Default Routes.

Nameservers enclosed in square brackets, separated with a comma and written indented underneath the keyword "nameservers":

```
nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Same structure applies to both IPv4 and IPv6 addressing.